# Delete in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, sql-delete

Is there any way to delete a range of records in cassandra.
I am doing this but getting error,

delete from tablename where id between 1 and 10 and dept='dev'

error:
"Only EQ and IN relation are supported on the partition key (unless you use the token() function) for DELETE statements"

Comment: do using range query using >,< operators.

Comment: getting same error for this also.

Comment: please send the query you are using.

Comment: delete from rawdata_flat where id >'165392504' and id< '218295742' and kpi='kpi'

Comment: delete from rawdata_flat where id >165392504 and id< 218295742 and kpi='kpi'  ....Try this. If it helps

Comment: show the table structure..

Comment: I had a statement like delete from tablename where non_primary_key_field = 'value' and got a similar error. what I had to do was run the query first and allow filtering then grab all the primary key values from the result and delete based on those values. So I ended up with delete from tablename where id in (value_1, value_2, value_3, etc.) and that worked.